# Namespaces in Python vs C++

Tags: python, c++, namespaces, using

What are the closest concepts in Python to `namespace` and `using` statements in C++?

Comment: Python also has namespaces, and the `with` context manager is broadly similar to `using`, I think.

Comment: I don't know C++ very well, but isn't `using` in C++ like `import` in Python?

Comment: @KSFT Not really. C++ doesn't have modules, so it has no equivalent to a python `import`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest equivalent to the `namespace` directive found in other languages is the Implicit Namespace Packages facility described in [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) and introduced in Python 3.3. It allows for modules in multiple locations to be combined into a single, unified namespace rather than forcing the import of the first valid candidate found in `sys.path`.

There is no direct equivalent of `using`; importing specific names from a module adds them to the local scope unilaterally.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't really an analogue. Consider this simple header:

```
// a.h
namespace ns {
    struct A { .. };
    struct B { .. };
}
```

If we were to do this:

```
#include "a.h"
using ns::A;
```

The point of that code is to be able to write `A` unqualified (as opposed to having to write `ns::A`). Now, you might consider a python equivalent as:

```
from a import A
```

But regardless of the `using`, the *entire* `a.h` header will still be included and compiled, so we would still be able to write `ns::B`, whereas in the Python version, `a.B` would not be visible.

The more expansive version:

```
using namespace ns;
```

definitely has no Python analogue either, since that brings in *all* names from `namespace ns` throughout the entire code-base - and namespaces can be reused. The most common thing I see beginner C++ programmers do is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std; // bring in EVERYTHING
```

That one line is *kind of* equivalent to:

```
from vector import *
from map import *
from algorithm import *
```

at least in what it does, but then it only actually brings in what's in `namespace std` - which isn't *necessarily* everything.